# How to create span using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have response from php in success of ajax,It is json object and i want to display each element in dynamically created span and click event on each span.I want all span should be in div1(div).I am trying below code.
Does I require for loop??
I want to create all span on single click event as I am calling $.ajax on single click for response.
Thanks.

```
$('<span/>', {
    'id':'myspan',
    'class':'myClass',
    'text':'Text Only',
}).on('click', function(){
    alert(this.id); // 
}).appendTo('#div1');
```

Comment: you should iterate through json object and for each iteration add that span to your existing div. You can add any functionality you like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're parsing your JSON into an object, this will allow you to loop through it (adjusting attributes as needed)

```
var span = $('<span/>');
span.click(function() { alert($(this).attr('id')); });
for (object in json) {
  span.attr('id',json[object]['id']).addClass(json[object]['class']).text(json[object]['text']);
  $('#div1').append(span);
}
```

Comment: your saying span will have id from data of json obj

Comment: @user3222876 Yes because you can only have one of any id on a page.

Comment: Fine but my span is not existing already to use span.clik and i want to create all span on single click.click event of created span I will handle afterwards

Comment: @user3222876 The span is being created by `var span = $('<span/>');` so it does exist by the time `span.click` is called.

Comment: take care about remove class after the insert, also append the dom once, after the loop, could be pertinent

Comment: @r043v From the question it sounds as though he's trying to add multiple `<span>`s at once.

Comment: hey I want span on every new line.For loop overriding spans